# Search for duplicates in each row and return which column has the duplicate?

Tags: r, duplicates, drop-duplicates

So I have poll data that I am looking at and I've been trying to create a script in R for it. Column 1 is the voter's name. The rest of the columns are the names of the people they voted for, across different category. I have 70 voters so I have 70 rows. I want to check for people voting for themselves. So I'm trying to check within row for any duplicates, namely any duplicates of the first cell of the row (ie, the voter's own name). I initially used the x[duplicated(x)] function, which worked well enough because it showed me which values were duplicates in the row. But I wasn't able to get a for loop running. So I'd have to do this all one-by-one. Any advice? Should I select the value in the first cell and search for that value in the rest of the row? How can I get it to let me know if the value IS duplicated and which column it appears in? Eventually I will want to take this information so that I can delete the self-votes. Thanks all!

Edit: here is example data frame.

```
voter_name <- c("John Smith", "Jane Doe", "John Doe", "Beyonce")
poll1 <- c("Spiderman", "The Hulk", "Superman", "Batman")
poll2 <- c("Red", "", "Purple", "Yellow")
poll3 <- c("Georgia", "", "Alaska", "Michigan")
poll4 <- c("John Smith", "John Doe", "Beyonce", "Jane Doe")
df <- data.frame(voter_name, poll1, poll2, poll3, poll4)
```

If I use the duplicated function, it does search through the first row for example and let me know that John Smith voted for himself for the last poll, which is what I want:

```
RowVector = as.character(df[1, ])
RowVector[duplicated(RowVector)]
```

Unfortunately, it also flags NA's and blanks as duplicates, so it also tells me that Jane Doe has 2 empty polls, which I don't care about. Ideally I could get it to ignore those. But my main issue is how to run this code through all 4 rows without typing it manually. And I only care if the voter name (column 1) is duplicated, so I don't actually want to see other duplicates. Thanks again!!

Comment: Would you pls `dput(head(your_data))` ?

Comment: Hi I don't think I can include my actual data (privacy concerns, since it is a poll with identifiable information), but I think I can find something similar to display the format at least

Comment: You can add dummy data to represent your needs

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I added code in my question with dummy data for an example of what I'm working with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to make a logical on all columns based on the `voter_name`, then we can pull all column names that have the same name.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-voter_name, ~ voter_name == .x),
         self_vote = pmap_chr(across(where(is.logical)), ~ toString(names(c(...))[which(c(...))]))) %>%
  select(voter_name, self_vote)
```

**Output**

```
  voter_name self_vote
1 John Smith     poll4
2   Jane Doe          
3   John Doe          
4    Beyonce
```

Or another option using a combination of `dplyr` and base R:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- mutate(df, across(-voter_name, ~ voter_name == .x))

result$self_vote <- apply(result, 1, function(x) names(which(x == T)))

result <- result[,c("voter_name", "self_vote")]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried the second option and it works with my example df but sadly it's not working on my actual data. Not sure why yet but I'm trying to parse out why it's not returning any "TRUE" responses for the first line... I think it's not recognizing duplicates but I'm not sure why. Gonna try the first option as well!

Comment: Update: The second option worked for me! Thanks so much!!!